# Установить перетаскиваемый балун (Яндекс.Карты)

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Нужен функционал, позволяющий самому кликнуть на Яндекс.Карты и установить там балун + получить координаты. Также нужна возможность перетаскивать этот балун.

Есть ли примеры реализации?

В документации нашёл только такой вариант: [Использование драггера](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/dragger). Но он плох тем, что `marker` — это отдельный слой, и в дальнейшем его спозиционировать по координатам невозможно.

Answer (score 1):

Мой код не работал, потому что я при создании карты передал вместо координат пустой массив и передал в ObjectManager строчку, а не объект. Вот рабочий пример:

```js
ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {
  var data_coord = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": 0,
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [55.831903, 37.411961]
      },
      "properties": {
        "balloonContent": "Содержимое балуна",
        "clusterCaption": "Еще одна метка",
        "hintContent": "Текст подсказки"
      }
    }]
  };
  var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
    center: [52, 31],
    zoom: 4
  }, {
    searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
  });
  var objectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager({
    // Чтобы метки начали кластеризоваться, выставляем опцию.
    clusterize: true,
    // ObjectManager принимает те же опции, что и кластеризатор.
    gridSize: 32
  });
  // Чтобы задать опции одиночным объектам и кластерам,
  // обратимся к дочерним коллекциям ObjectManager.
  objectManager.objects.options.set('preset', 'islands#greenDotIcon');
  objectManager.clusters.options.set('preset', 'islands#greenClusterIcons');
  myMap.geoObjects.add(objectManager);
  objectManager.add(data_coord);
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru-RU"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://yandex.st/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```